# Why can I use ollama with in a virtual environemt created by nix-shell but not when created by a flake

Tags: nix, nix-flake, ollama

the command `nix-shell -p ollama` works fine. In the virtual environment I can do that.

```
 ollama start &
 ollama run mistral
```

I can now use the mistral llm chatbot.

But when I use a flake like this one.

```
{

 inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

 outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        ollama=pkgs.ollama;
       in {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = [
            pkgs.curl
            ollama
           ];
        };
      }); }
```

it doesn't work. although the command to create the environment

> nix develop works

fine

THe problem occurs when I try to use ollama inside the environment

```
ollama.start # if don't do that before ollama.run I get a message that say that ollama hasn't started yet.
```

returns this error:

> Error: $HOME is not defined

I have the same problem ollama.serve

Comment: Are you using the `-i` / `--ignore-env` argument to `nix develop`? Don't do that unless you want it to do what its documentation says it does. :)

Comment: ...there's an override to let you flag environment variables to keep, if you prefer to go that route; `--keep HOME`, repeat for any other variables you don't want thrown out.

Comment: (btw, if you shown us exactly which arguments you passed when invoking `nix develop`, we wouldn't have to guess).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You re right I used -i. Next time I will exactly show which argument I passed. But it didn't solve the problem. Now I have this error message. "Error: unmarshal: invalid character 'p' after top-level value". And strangely when I tried again with -i and I the previous problem disappeared but I have "Error: unmarshal: invalid character 'p' after top-level value"  too. I read this ( https://github.com/ollama/ollama/issues/2293 )but it didn't help

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think it works now. I will post an answer later. Thanks for your help. I will give an answer to this question later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have to run `nix develop` alone not `nix develop -i` or you should at least write `--keep HOME`

If you tried to use ollama with nix-shell. Check that ollama process is not running anymore int the background.

Otherwise you have this error:

> Error: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:11434: bind: address already in use

to solve this error:

```
  netstat -ltnup | grep ':11434'
```

You get 51454/ollama

```
   kill 51454
```

now ollama run mistral works